# Measurability problem of sample distribution function of a contiuum of independent random variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $I = [0,1]$ be the index set of a contiuum of i.i.d random variables. For each $t \in I$, the sample space of $X_t$ is $\Bbb R$ equipped with Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Borel probability measure. By [Kolmogorov extension theorem](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/Kolmogorov.pdf), we have a unique probability measure on the sample space $\Omega = {\Bbb R}^{I}$.

Specifically, for each Lebesgue measurable subset of $\Bbb R$, $A$, we have $A^t = \{\omega \in \Omega: \omega(t) = A\}$. Then all sets of the form $A_t$ constitute a $\pi$-system that generates the $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$, which is, $\mathscr{F}$. The measure $\mu$ of $\Omega$ must be consistent with finite dimentional distributions in the sense that: $$\mu(A^t) = m(A)$$ $$\mu(\bigcap_{1 \leq i \leq n}A^{t_i}) = \prod_{1 \leq i \leq n} \mu(A^{t_i}) $$
The mapping $i \mapsto t_i$ is one-on-one for each $n$.$(\omega, \mathscr{F}, \mu)$ is the desired probability space.

For each $c \in \Bbb R$, the **sample distribution function** $F_{\omega}(\cdot)$ is defined as: $$F_{\omega}(c) = l(\{ t \in I: X_t(\omega) \leq c\})$$ $l$ is the lesbesgue measure.

In [Judd(1985)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022053185900596)(Paywall required), in $\sf {ZFC}$, $\omega_c = \{t \in I: X_t(\omega)  \leq c\}$ could be non-measurable, thus $F_{\omega}(c)$ could also be non-measurable.

Here's screenshot of the theorem:

[image]
[image]
[image]

$\mu^{\ast}(N)$ and $\mu_{\ast}(N)$ are outer and inner measures of $N$ respectively.

**Question:** What does it mean "any Borel set is restricted on at most a countable number of indices" in the Fifth line of the proof?

Comment: The answer is given IN THE NEXT SENTENCE, starting with "That is". A paraphrase is that every Borel set can be written as $B\times\mathbb R^{I\setminus J}$ where $J\subset I$ is at most countable and $B$ is in the Borel sigma-algebra of $\mathbb R^J$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can check that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $A_t$ consists of the sets of the form $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid (\omega(t_j),j\geqslant 1)\in B\}$, where $(t_j,j\geqslant 1)$ is a sequence of real numbers, and $B$ a Borel subsets of $\mathbb R^{\infty}$, the set of sequences of real numbers endowed with the product Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

The main difficulty here is to prove that this collection is closed under countable unions.

Comment: Replace "a sequence of Borel subsets" by "a Borel subset". (Unrelated to this misprint, I fail to see how this answers the OP's query.)

Comment: @Did Thanks for the catch of the misprint. I believed the OP asked about a justification about the claim in the next sentence (but I would wait for a clarification for him/her).

Comment: Sorry for my delay to response(In the meantime, I went out to buy a copy of Billingsley's Probability and measure). I think you answered my question. At the beginning, I confused it with the fact that Borel Algebra has the cardinality of $\mathfrak{c}$. A layman's mistake. Now I see it's a transfinite induction terminating before $\omega_1$.

Comment: Wow. How is THIS even related to the "Question" in the question eludes me. But hey, since everybody is happy...

Answer (score 3):

A general fact of measure theory is that if $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{F}$ a family of subsets and $B\in\sigma(\mathcal{F})$, then there exists a countable subfamily $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ such that $B\in\sigma(\mathcal{C})$. In order to prove this, one just has to verify that the sets with this property form a $\sigma$-algebra containing all elements of $\mathcal{F}$. Applied to product spaces, if a set is in the product-$\sigma$-algebra, then it is generated by countably many coordinate projections.

For a modern account of the problem Judd discusses, see the introduction of Podczeck, [On existence of rich Fubini extensions](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00199-009-0458-9#page-1) (paywall). The problem was known for quite some time before Judd. Doob already mentioned that sample-realizations will usually be non-measurable. In the paper [Zur Gleichwertigkeit zweier Arten der Randomisierung](https://eudml.org/doc/154201) from 1974, von Weizsäcker has Judd's proof as a step in the proof of his main theorem.

See also the [related discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102386/is-a-random-subset-of-the-real-numbers-non-measurable-is-the-set-of-measurable) on Mathoverflow.