# Uncountably infinite throws at a point on a dartboard

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Choose a point on a dartboard and call it a success, then throw uncountably infinite darts at the board. Is the probability of hitting the target one or more times greater than zero?

This version of the problem may be ill-posed as throws of a dart should be indexable by positive integers; then, more generally speaking, if you choose at random an uncountable set of points in the circle, what is the probability of your previously chosen point lying in this set? Perhaps this is also ill-posed.

Comment: What do you mean "choose at random"? There are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ such sets, only a small part of which are "legitimate events" that we can assign probability to.

Comment: In general, choosing randomly from an uncountable set is pretty hard to define. You really need to specify exactly your process of choosing randomly; in particular, it's easy to accidentally build a process that uses the axiom of choice to construct unmeasurable events, which pretty well prevents any study of probability.

Comment: sigma algebras allow for countable operations, this is not going to work out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_algebra

Comment: And please clarify what you mean by a "point". Do you mean a bounded area of the board or a single infinitesimally-sized co-ordinate location?

Comment: @MattClarke I'm referring to the latter, a single coordinate. I hadn't considered the fact that sigma algebras are only closed under countable operations.

Comment: @PaulZ How could we define choosing randomly from an uncountable set properly in this context (i.e. in a way that allows us to study probabilities)?

Comment: The question is posed as 2-dimensional -- points within a circle -- but is it any different from the 1D formulation of choosing values in R?

Comment: @MattClarke The question could be equally defined in one dimension, yes. But I like to throw darts.

Comment: Let's see, three darts in a turn, say 5 seconds in total. An uncountably infinite number of darts divided by three and multiplied by 5 secs, gives .... hmmmm, you're not going to be finished by closing time are you?

Comment: The event of success will not be measurable in the product $\sigma$-algebra, essentially for the reasons given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/448291/21674).

Comment: @Matt: If you really think about the time line as a continuum then every uncountable set has a condensation point. Therefore, there exists a plank time in which uncountably many throws occur. The amount of energy released in that plank time is likely to obliterate the universe, and create a subsequent big bang. This is a plausible answer to "what was before the big bang?", "a very busy darts game".